# Какой метод будет вызван?

Tags: java

Вопрос был озвучен на собеседовании:

```
void test(String s) {...}
void test(Object s) {...}
test(null);
```

Почему вызывается test(String s)?

Comment: test(String s) не будет вызван, потому что в вашем примере никто ничего  вообще не вызывает.

Comment: будет вызван test(String s), Максим

Comment: @Maxim, вы говорите, что java увидев метод с пустым телом вообще его вызывать не будет?

Comment: @alvoro не внимательно посмотрел, показалось, что все три строчки относятся к интерфейсу

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если вы перегружаете метод, то будет вызван тот метод, у которого типы аргументов наиболее близко совпадают с тем типом параметров, переданных при вызове.

Как определяется ***близость***? По принципу *от конкретного к более общему*.

Рассмотрим ваш пример:
Есть метод принимающий `String`, есть метод принимающий `Object`. `String` наследуется от `Object`.
`null` является `String`? Да является, следовательно, выбирается метод принимающий параметр с данным типом.